# How to fix resolveip returning multiple ip addresses?

Tags: arch-linux, host-name-resolution

I switched to a different distribution on my Raspberry Pi and am facing difficulties dicovering it by its hostname from my notebook. I can ssh to it but not ping it (both works fine using the ip address).

When I tried `resolveip` it returns multiple 
addresses:

```
[tim@nb-tim ~]$ resolveip raspberrypi
IP address of raspberrypi is 192.168.178.31
IP address of raspberrypi is 192.168.178.32
IP address of raspberrypi is 192.168.178.34
```

Where the first one is the one it used to have and the last one is current one.

How can I fix this and only receive one ip address again?

In case it is relevant: I am using Arch Linux (on both systems) and my router is a FritzBox 7490.

Comment: I know I can fix it "temporarily" by adding an entry to `/etc/hosts`, but I would like to fix the root of the problem.

Comment: Does `resolveip` just do DNS lookups? Then how is your DNS being managed? Sounds like you have multiple `A` records for that name.

Comment: I do not manage it manually. I just entered the FritzBox ip in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: What is providing DNS on your network? Maybe a router, for example?

Comment: Yes, the router is providing DNS (that is what I meant when I wrote FritzBox).

Comment: ... then it probably is serving out all the old IP addresses, and you need to use its interface to clear them out.